# MongoDB: How to get data from linked collection based on condition

Tags: mongodb

I have a type collection that stores field informations. Each field has a type: Input, SelectBox, MultiSelect. Some field types have predefined options with key and label.

Here is an example of a type document:

```
{
    id: 't-123'
    attributes: [
       {
          id: 'a-1',
          type: 'INPUT'
       },
       {
          id: 'a-2',
          type: 'SELECT',
          option: [
             {key: 'DE', label: 'Germany'},
             {key: 'US', label: 'United States'}
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, I have a form collection that references the type collection and stores all filled fields from a user.

Here is an example of a form document:

```
{
    id: 'f-1',
    type: 't-123',
    values: [
      {attribute: 'a-1', value: 'my random string'},
      {attribute: 'a-2', value: 'DE'} 
    ]
}
```

Now, I am trying to query the form collection and automatically add the choosen key/label object from the type collection for fields with type: SELECT. I am wondering if I can do this in mongoDB or only in node.js.

Here is my desired result:

```
{
    id: 'f-1',
    type: 't-123',
    values: [
      {attribute: 'a-1', value: 'my random string'},
      {attribute: 'a-2', value: {key:'DE', label:'Germany'}} 
    ]
}
```

So the query needs to check if the attribute.type is equal to 'SELECT', and find the related object from the options array, based on the key stored in the form. Else it takes the value stored in the form document.

Can I do anything like this within my MongoDB query or do I have to loop through my database results and manipulate the data manually ? THX!!

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/